# How to add custom authorization attribute to AuthorizeView?

Tags: blazor

I am rewriting a WebForms app to Blazor.  The current system uses the numbers 1 through 5 to show the user's 'access level' to indicate which menu items/webpages they have access to.

I have created a custom authorization attribute to support this access level functionality (temporarily). The new attribute follows Microsoft's guidance:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/iauthorizationpolicyprovider?view=aspnetcore-5.0

The attribute [AccessLevelList("4", "5")] works in the WebAPI. When I try it in the client NavMenu  to limit menu item visibility, I cannot find the proper syntax for it to work. Anything else results in the attribute not being found or it will not compile.

I have tried Policy='AccessLevelList("4", "5")', but this requires the single-quotes which results in the *string value* of the attribute being passed directly to the authorization policy provider rather than the attribute being passed to the *attribute* class.

Update 7/19/21:
<strike>Any suggestions on making this work?</strike>
Since the Policy attribute requires a string value, how do I get the AuthorizeView to accept my new custom attribute directly?

Update 7/20/21:
Successfully created a custom AuthorizeView component:
`<CustomAuthorizeView AccessLevelList="4,5">` and using the AuthenticationState I am able to validate the user's claim against the required claims. How do I notify that the user is not authorized to view the menu item so that the render fragment is not displayed?  Do I have to create a custom AuthenticationStateProvider?

Comment: can you please clarify the question.

Comment: I think you can create a component let's say NewAuthorizeView which drives from AuthorizeView then it should have a property like AccessLevelList in which you wrap your policy with this property